# Calling a Node.js function/file from C# in Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio

Is it possible to do this?

Let's say I want to use Node.js to make an http request.

Here would be my Node code saved in NodeExample.js:

```
var http = require('http');
var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;

var options = {
    host: 'somehostexample.com',
    path: '/pathexample',
    headers: { 'Accept-Language': 'en-US', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
}

http.get(options, (response) => {
    response.on(('data'), (chunk) => { body += chunk })
    response.on('end', () => {
        var data = JSON.parse(jbody)
        console.log(data)
    })
})
```

Could I make a main C# file in the same Visual Studio solution/directory and do something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace willCallNode
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             NodeExample ne = new NodeExample()
             ne.someFunction()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://tjanczuk.github.io/edge/

Comment: Is there a simpler way to do this in Visual Studio'

Comment: If you want to run Node function in C#, you have to bring Node into the .Net execution context.  No, there isn't a simpler way.

Comment: There are plenty of posts discussing how to invoke external process from C# (and likely many other integrating NodeJs and .Net tighter than `Process.Start`). If you can narrow down what acceptable options are (and show links to ones don't work) question would be much better.

Comment: why don't you expose a http method in NodeJS and call it using HttpClient in C#?

Comment: How would I go about doing that? Is it similar in fashion to what I was trying to show above?